# Returned incomplete results using multiple select into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
  NAMES STATUS
  AMY   Existing
  Bob   Added
```

The Expected Results would be

```
    Existing    Added   Removed
    Amy         Bob
```

```
SELECT a.[Existing], b.[Added], c.[Removed] from 
(SELECT [NAMES] from [dbo].[EXAMPLE]
WHERE [STATUS] = 'Existing'
) as a, 
(SELECT [NAMES] from [dbo].[EXAMPLE]
WHERE [STATUS] = 'Added'
) as b,
(SELECT [NAMES] from [dbo].[EXAMPLE]
WHERE [STATUS] = 'Removed'
) as c
```

However, the results are empty:

```
Existing    Added   Removed
```

if I remove the select of table c, the results for the table a, and table b will show up. What is wrong with my SELECT statement?

UPDATE: 
With the help of Gordan, my refined query looks like this now, and it gets the results I wanted, but not quite in the order I wanted

```
select (case when [STATUS] = 'Existing' then [NAME] end) as existing,
       (case when [STATUS] = 'Added' then [NAME] end) as added,
       (case when [STATUS] = 'Removed' then [NAME] end) as removed    
from (select [STATUS], [NAME]
      from e
      ) a
```

Results:

```
existing    added   removed
AMY         NULL    NULL
NULL        Bob     NULL
```

Comment: SQL in this website is meant to indicate SQL as laugauge (ANSI/ISO SQL standards).. This SQL dialect seams to be SQL Server (MSSQL), SQLite, MariaDB (with [SQL_MODE=MSSQL](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sql_modemssql/)), please tags the correct one..  But i noticed `dbo` i assume you are using SQL Server (MSSQL)

Comment: i assume status column in your table does not have a unique key? Or the table does not has unique keys at all?  maybe it's better to include the CREATE TABLE structure..

Comment: @RaymondNijland This is just a code snippet, this query will be a part of alarger logic. Thanks for your comment tho.

Comment: By the way is there application code (programming language) involved? As data display issues are in general beter solved in the application..

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you want conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when status = 'Existing' then name end) as existing,
       max(case when status = 'Added' then name end) as added,
       max(case when status = 'Removed' then name end) as removed      
from (select e.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by status) as seqnum
      from e
     ) e
group by seqnum;
```

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. I got some success. without the seqnum and the group by statement I get the results i wanted, but the order of each columns are random. However, if i include the group by, some errors came up, a.STATUS, a.NAME are not in the aggregated function.

Comment: *"but the order of each columns are random"* @BillLau in ANSI/ISO SQL standards everthing is **orderless**  ... Meaning you will have to use `ORDER BY` but then the results can still be non derministic ("random") when values are equal.. Meaning to get a derministic ("fixed") order you will have to include atleast one column in the `ORDER BY` that has unique values meaning having a `PRIMARY` or `UNiQUE` key..

Comment: This will work fine as long as there's only three names max, and they each only have one of the statuses listed, and no status is duplicated... but what if two names have the status of `added`? Say, Amy is added. Then what? I know what the above query will do. This is more of a question for the OP: What should the expected result be?

Comment: with other words.. @TechGnome  this is generally beter done in application code as the main problem is a data display issue..

Comment: I will try to do this on the application levels. I was exploring different options to find the optimal way of getting the results I wanted.